# cordova window.location.href behaviour error

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

In my `assets/www/index.html`, I am trying to open html in the 
`/data/data/files/xyz/index.html` with this javascript command:

```
window.location.href = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "xyz/index.html";
```

In the `../xyz/index.html` it also included the `cordova.js` which exists on the same xyz directory:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The `index.html` can be loaded, but in the catlog show error like below

> W/CordovaWebViewImpl﹕ Blocked (possibly sub-frame) navigation to
>   non-allowed URL: gap://ready

is there something wrong with my method? Is it wrong to use `window.location.href` to open another cordova application in the data folder ?

EDIT : I already found the root cause, that is my cordova.js in the /data/data/files/xyz/cordova.js is having different version with the one in asset folder. after i copied the same cordova js version, it can be loaded without error warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use "cordova.file.datadirectory".  That's only if you use the file plugin for accessing *data* files, such as saving high-scores in a game or level data.  You do not use the plugin for loading/unloading pages into the current webview.

You would want all of your HTML files to be in the same folder branch as your "index.html".  Assume a directory structure like this:

```
/ index.html      <!---- this is your current index.html

/ page2.html      

/ js / index.js

/ xyz /index.html
```

All you would have to do is `window.location='xyz/index.html'`.  However, I *strongly* encourage you to not replace entire pages if you're developing for iOS. It's almost a guarenteed way to get your app rejected.  Try loading your pages in via AJAX using a framework like "[Framework7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7)".

NOTE: You can only view files within the webview, that are in the same folder or are children of, as your initial index.html.

EDIT: You want to load another Cordova webview application.  I'd suggest still making it a child of the initial "index.html" folder.  However, you might be able to write a plugin or customize the platform itself to access the other files.  However, that's out of the scope of this question!

Comment: I assume you have to reload all your required js as well when taking this approach (i.e. cordova.js / all plugins)?

Comment: If replacing the entire page, yes.

Comment: yup, i want to replace the entire page with another index.html in the application data directory. this index.html is downloaded from web services. in the index.html the  all scripts are reloaded. but in the cat log show those warnings.

Comment: Will the plugins be different between Cordova projects?  What you could do, as a workaround, is load the new "index.html" via AJAX and JavaScript, and then replace the entire DOM with what you just downloaded from the server.

Comment: they use different javascripts files.

Comment: As a warning, make sure your apps are pretty lean - the UIWebView (on iOS, if you're targeting that platform) is a memory hog; loading a new page into view wont' clear it's memory usage.  Only destroying and recreating the view will help reclaim the memory.